# Jumblr Api query returns maximum of 50 Posts

Tags: android, tumblr

I am creating an android app and using the Jumblr Api for Tumblr . In the Tumblr console when i query for posts with a limit of 100, it returns 100 posts(or less if the page has less than 100 posts) But Using Jumblr , if i query for a limit higher than 50 , it returns 20 posts even when the page has more than 20 posts . Is this a bug or is there another way around this ???

Help is needed (In any Form)

Comment: Tumblr v2 API states the limit is 20 posts per request: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts I am not sure why the other values work sadly.

Comment: Alright , How am I supposed to get the next 20 posts ?? (Help Needed)

Comment: By using `offset`. Add 20 to this after each request?

Comment: Wow !!! How did i Miss that ??!! Thank You, thats definitely An Answer.

Comment: No problem at all. Feel free to answer your own question, I don't know anything about Jumblr. :D

Answer (score 1):

Alright, Just incase you came here for answer , all you have to do is set the offset at 50 in the next query and 100 in the next and so on.

Thanks to @mikedidthis